# Install Hue on the standard Hadoop core 2.6 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, installation, hue

I installed hadoop core 2.6 on Ubuntu. Can I install hue on top of the standard hadoop 2.6? I am running into issues after I followed through all the steps.

Did anyone got the complete installation up and running with hue on the standard hadoop 2.6 core?

I also read this on the install guide on hue webpage
***Hue requires the Hadoop contained in Cloudera’s Distribution including Apache Hadoop (CDH), version 3 update 4 or later***

I did read on some questions on stackoverflow that they could install it so I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking at old docs, Hue works with any Hadoop. If you use standard Hadoop you could try the [latest tarball release](http://gethue.com/category/release/) or BigTop (good but lagging a bit). Feel free to check the 'Configure' menu of [gethue.com](http://gethue.com).